# Why my angular controller does not initialize vm vars?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [controller as](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#style-y032) syntax in my angular web app and from the controller I call a factory which does REST GET calls to a url with a var `menuTitle` path parameter:

```
angular.module('cmApp').factory('menuDataFactory', [ '$http', function($http) {

    var urlBase = '/app_api/menu';
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.getHeaderMenu = function(menuTitle) {
        return $http.get(urlBase + "/headerMenu/" + menuTitle, {
            cache : true
        });
    };
```

In the **controller** I have a function which I tried to use to load different results for this menu calls, eg:

```
        vm = this;
        // registered user menus
        vm.planMenuGroup = getHeaderMenuGroup("plan");
        vm.planContentMenuGroup = getHeaderMenuGroup("plan_content");
        vm.buyMenuGroup = getHeaderMenuGroup("buy");
        vm.buyContentMenuGroup = getHeaderMenuGroup("buy_content");
        vm.manageMenuGroup = getHeaderMenuGroup("manage");
        vm.manageContentMenuGroup = getHeaderMenuGroup("manage_content");

        function getHeaderMenuGroup(menuTitle) {
            menuDataFactory.getHeaderMenu(menuTitle).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong when initializing this vm vars because the data is returned but they are not initialized with that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

`vm.planMenuGroup = getHeaderMenuGroup("plan");`

then

`vm.planMenuGroup` 
will always be undefined because `getHeaderMenuGroup("plan");` returns nothing. It calls an asynchronous function, and you need to assign the data in the callback, like this:

```
function getHeaderMenuGroup(controllerVar, menuTitle) {
     menuDataFactory.getHeaderMenu(menuTitle).then(function (response) {
           controllerVar = response.data;
     });
}
```

And to use it:

```
vm = this;
// registered user menus
getHeaderMenuGroup(vm.planMenuGroup, "plan");
```